# Ensure at least one property is provided to function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to pass in either 1 of the 3 parameter string to the function. Is the following the best way? I am thinking if there is another more elegant way.

```
function (a: Option1 | Option2 | Option3) {
   // some code here
 }

interface Option1 {
  a: string
  b?: string
  c?: string
}

interface Option2 {
  a?: string
  b: string
  c?: string
}

interface Option3 {
  a?: string
  b?: string
  c: string
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use a mapped type to solve this! We should, for each key, make that key required and all others optional.

To make everything else optional, we could **omit** the key and use the built-in  **Partial** type.

And for just getting the key, we can use the built-in **Pick** type.

Finally, for the desired type, we intersect these:

```
type AtLeastOne<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: Pick<T, K> & Partial<Omit<T, K>>;
}[keyof T];
```

Here's how you would use it:

```
type A = AtLeastOne<Option>; // create the possible types

function a(a: A) {} // and use it here
```

A few example calls:

```
a({}); // ! error

a({ a: "" });
a({ b: "" });
a({ c: "" });

a({ a: "", b: "" });
a({ a: "", b: "", c: "" });
a({ a: "", c: "" });
```

As you can see, you must provide at least one property to the function. Try it out yourself [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=21&pln=16&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYmQbwChkTk4AuZAZzClAHMBuY0gI0prpCZZIQ9oNmAX0KEwAT3QoAgmAAyEODVQgIAHgAqAPmQBeAr2QBtANLJQyANYQJ2GMk0BdSgAVgCK1oA0yU7oAyZFc4KCw4ABt1VABbYDAfP21tEWMbOwdnZnEpWX1kOUVlMFUNDCxcFMIAemrSAD0AfjEYAFcQBAq8OAAKCgKASgJRQl78YQHssbJKACJZ5AnmafZkecXJ0Z78ZH41haWxaf7531X1w+O52bPr3z2Lzav9++uN5iA).

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is this?:

```
function (type: OptionType) {
    // some code here
}

type OptionType = Option1 | Option2 | Option3;

interface Option1 {
    a: string
    b?: string
    c?: string
}

interface Option2 {
    a?: string
    b: string
    c?: string
}

interface Option3 {
    a?: string
    b?: string
    c: string
}
```

Comment: There is no difference, right? I just tested both code

Comment: No it's the exact same thing. Just without explicitly writing out all possible types inside the parameter list. I don't think there is a cleaner way to do it than that.